# Problems Zebra Striping a single column in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've been trying to zebra stripe the first column in my table but I've been unsuccessful. I've been trying things such as the below without but that seems to highlight them all.

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd) td:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

Can someone assist in this?

This is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CTRlMFnw4bxXy8wYHTSP?p=preview) of the code in question.

Comment: Have you seen that the plunker is full of errors ?

Comment: @vals Yes, it's part of the test code I've been writing so there's tags which I haven't yet removed etc, just wanted to pop it up because it runs, definitely will clean it up later.

Comment: http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/css-table-color-columns.php

Comment: @morne Unfortunately that link doesn't help my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `ng-class` directive.

Add `ng-class="{even: $even, odd: $odd}"` into your table row (`<tr />`), and update your CSS like this :

```
tr.odd td:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Your repeater should look like below :

```
<tr class="tt" ng-class="{even: $even, odd: $odd}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click for more information on {{x.c}}." ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" ng-repeat-start="x in projects | filter:query | filter:myFilter | orderBy:orderProperty">
   <td class="shrink"><b>{{x.a}}</b></td>
   <td class="shrink">{{x.b}}</td>
   <td class="shrink"><u>{{x.c}}</u></td>
   <td class="shrink">{{x.d}}</td>
   <td class="shrink">{{x.e}}</td>
   <td class="shrink">{{x.f}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here's [a working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KFLbbz0k7ZBcETSvo3L9?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for the help That works perfectly. Was the issue due to the fact that the table is populated using AngularJS? It's the only thing I can think of that would cause the issue I was having before.